# Execute function with variable from imported file

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to execute function with value from other file as variable.

one file (let's assume text.py) containing:

```
VAR="abc"
```

In main file:

```
variable1 -> that variable contain value "VAR"
import text
```

Execute function:

```
example_function(connect=text.variable1)
```

Why I cannot do it this way?

EDIT:

real code:

```
variable = "VAR_23_23"
import text
from functionfile import number_function
from functionfile import find_number
number_to_substr=find_number(variable,"_",1)
source_var=variable[:number_to_substr]
number_function(connect=text.source_var)
```

Edit 2.

text.py contain:

```
VAR="abc"
```

main.my contain:

```
    import text

    variable = "VAR_23_23"        
    from functionfile import number_function
    from functionfile import find_number

    number_to_substr=find_number(variable,"_",1)   -> the result is "4"
    source_var=variable[:number_to_substr]  -> the result is "VAR"
    number_function(connect=text.source_var) -> now trying to execute function with that variable name but as result I expect value from TEXT.py file.
```

For now instead of 'abc' value I got 'VAR' value.`

Comment: This isn't really clear. Doesn't `text.VAR` work to get the value of `VAR` from `text.py` (after importing it)?

Comment: Please post real code snippets that will show working piece of code.

Comment: `variable1` is defined within the current module of `main`, so `text.variable1` overall is not correct

Comment: just edited my post. regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `text.variable1` because `variable1` resides in your main file.

You can either use the value from the imported file:

```
import text
example_function(connect=text.VAR)
```

Or use the value in `variable1`:

```
example_function(connect=variable1)
```

If what you're trying to do is as I've posted in my comment then this is what you should change in order to make it work:

First, edit the `text.py` file so that instead of containing an instantiation of a variable named `VAR`, it contains an instantiation of a dictionary containing a `"VAR"` key:

```
d = {'VAR': "abc"}
```

Now, in order to access the value of `'VAR'` in the main file, do `text.d[source_var]`. That is,

```
number_function(connect=text.d[source_var])
```

This is assuming that the `source_var` variable contains the string `"VAR"`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I edited my question. Please take a look what exactly i meant

Comment: For now "variable" is static but I want to make it as input variable.

Comment: the thing is that I cannot use static value as you mentioned: (connect=text.VAR). -> Cannot put "VAR" as static here. only as variable.. Unfornatelly your second solution does not work properly : (

Comment: @maciek2791, if the whole content of `text.py` is as posted in your question (`VAR="abc"`) and in the main file you `import text`, then you should be able to access the value of `VAR` in the main file by `text.VAR`. Are you getting an error when trying to access `VAR` that way?

Comment: again I edited my post. Hope now it is clear... have no idea what is wrong, but the result is not as I expected : ( Thanks

Comment: @maciek2791, Maybe I get what you're trying to do. Let me know if I'm right. You have a string `variable` whose value happens to be `"VAR_23_23"`. You're trying to get a substring of the `variable` string such that the substring contains a sequence of characters starting at the beginning and ending at the first digit in the string (In your case the substring is `"VAR_"`  (But you were saying the substring is `"VAR"`, not `"VAR_"` which I believe is an error of yours). Now you want to take the substring (`"VAR_"`) and retrieve the value of a variable of the same name from `text.py`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are totally right. by the way value from substring function is "VAR" - it works fine. : )

Comment: by the way I was trying to use " import text " and tried to print that variable eg. print (text.VAR)  - but i got an error message "module" object has no attribute 'VAR'

Comment: @maciek2791, I've edited my answer. Try my new solution.

Comment: @ snakile  . It works perfectly, but could you explain me please why this time it works, why it did not work before? Is it what you use is some kind of array variable ?

Comment: @maciek2791, In `text.py` we've defined a Python dictionary. A dictionary is a data structures mapping keys (such as the `"VAR"` string) into values (such as `"abc"`). For more info on dictionaries see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries. It didn't work before because you cannot convert a string (such as `"VAR"`) into a variable name (such as `VAR`).

Comment: I get it. Thanks once again ! regards